# Security for database SQLite of apps

Tags: sqlite

I'm beginner in eclipse and android apps. what can I do for security of database? prevent hack or steel my database of my app. And where is database of apps in mobiles with android OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is pretty trivial to get it, no matter what you do. If you want to keep your data **safer**, you can drop the local database, and make a web service where you get your data from. Then you will have to make some restrictions, so people will not rip your data fast. This is known as anti-farming and you can see more at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Anti-farming

But this will only slow people down, and as the article says, large resource adversaries will still be able to get whatever they want.

**What to do:** don't focus on it, build a awesome app, so no other will reach your user level/profit.

Comment: thanks but I don't want send data to server.My app work offline. any better and easy way?

Comment: In practice no. Imagine you encrypted your database, and only made one method that decrypts your data. Assume that this method is written in super weird way, making really hard to reverse engineer. Well then I can just extract your .class file, where the method is in and use it directly. There is of course other ways you could make scramble it, but still, it is just a matter of time if people are interested in it.

Comment: Thanks @Smarties89 .  I wrote algorithm to disassemble data and other method corrects it, So you mean, users can hack and access my source code and figure out whats that algorithm or method?

Comment: @tara1367 yes. I could pontentially just take your program, and then use the same method that corrects it and then use it. The best solution is to either don't think about it, and use your time on your app, or use a webservice for the data. They are both fail if you have a pesistent and patient attacker.

Comment: No I don't want use a web-service for my data. I think , maybe exist the other way for protect source code!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/. It is possible to create a encrypted database with that library. You should only think about where to place the key of it. One possible solution is that user has to enter the password via login dialog for example.

The database and app specific data is located at /android /data/package of your app folder.